# EntityFramework, Migrations e MySql. Nome de Schema sendo interpretado de forma errada. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migrations

Estou com um problema ao utilizar migrations com o **MySql**.

Quando tento criar a primeira versão com `Migrations` ele está fazendo do **schema/nome do banco** parte do nome da tabela:

```cs
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "vendas.produto",  // Aqui
            c => new
                {
                    ...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
        CreateTable(
            "vendas.vendaitem", // aqui
            c => new
                {
                    ...
                })
            ....
            .Index(t => t.ProdutoId);
        
        CreateTable(
            "vendas.venda", // e aqui
            c => new
                {
                    ...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);            
    }
```

Estou tentando fazer a engenharia reversa de uma base existente para um mapeamento ***Code First*** com **EntityFramework**, então criei uma outra base, mais simples, só para simular o problema:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `vendas` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `venda` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DataVenda` date NOT NULL,
  `SubTotal` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Desconto` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Total` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

... entre outras
```

Utilizando o **EntityFramework Power Tools** eu fiz o mapeamento que gerou as classes simples e os mapeamentos por ***Fluent API***.

Exemplo da classe `Venda`:

```cs
public class venda
{
    public venda()
    {
        vendaitems = new List<vendaitem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataVenda { get; set; }
    public double SubTotal { get; set; }
    public double Desconto { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<vendaitem> vendaitems { get; set; }
}
```

E seu mapeamento:

```cs
public class vendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<venda>
{
    public vendaMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("venda", "vendas"); // <-- Aqui está o schema/database name

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(t => t.DataVenda).HasColumnName("DataVenda");
        Property(t => t.SubTotal).HasColumnName("SubTotal");
        Property(t => t.Desconto).HasColumnName("Desconto");
        Property(t => t.Total).HasColumnName("Total");
    }
}
```

Pelo o que entendo, para a primeira versão com *Migrations*, estando o mapeamento equivalente ao banco de dados existente a atualização do banco de dados (com `update-database` no **Package Manager Console**) deveria gerar os métodos `Up` e `Down` vazios e somente a tabela `Migrations` seria adicionada no banco de dados.

Porém, o `Migrations` de todas as tabelas são criadas e o comando `Update-Database` utilizando o `Migrations` gerado faz com que outras tabelas sejam criadas com os nomes `vendas.venda, vendas.produto, venda.vendaitem`.

Para utilizar o EntityFramework Power Tools para fazer o mapeamento configurei meu App.config com o seguinte código:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" requirePermission="false" 
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
    EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VendasContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    connectionString="server=localhost;user id=USUARIO; password=SENHA; 
    persistsecurityinfo=True; database=Vendas" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, 
    MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
       type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
        description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Instalei via NuGet:

1. **EntityFramework**
2. **MySql.Data**
3. **MySql.Data.Entity.EF6**

A versão do **EntityFramework** é a **6.1.3** com **.Net 4.5**.
A versão do **MySql.Data** e **MySql.Data.Entity.EF6** é **6.9.6**.

Minha classe `Configuration` do `Migrations`:

```cs
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Models.VendasContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", 
            new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator()); // necessário para usar 
                // Migrations com MySql
    }
}
```

Configuração na classe do Contexto:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new produtoMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new vendaMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new vendaitemMap());

    modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));
}
```

Tendo essas informações, como posso resolver o problema com o `Migrations`?

---

### Adicionando mais detalhes:

Esse é o banco que estou mapeando com o **EntityFramework Power Tools**:

[image: banco de dados original]

Então, após o uso da engenharia reversa com o **EntityFramework Power Tools** eu adiciono um migrations (`Add-Migration Initial`) que gera o primeiro trecho de código de `DbMigration` dessa pergunta.

Veja o nome que ele deu a tabela **Vendas** (`"vendas.venda"`).

Então, efetuo o `Update-Database` e meu banco fica assim:

[image: banco de dados alterado]

Enfim, o `Migrations` gerado faz com que outras tabelas sejam criadas com os nomes `vendas.venda, vendas.produto, venda.vendaitem`.

Imagino que prefixo/schema/nome de banco não deveria ser adicionado ao nome da tabela ao criar a versão de `Migrations` (primeiro trecho de código da pergunta). E apenas criaria os métodos `Up` e `Down` vazios e, com isso, ao efetuar o comando `Update-Database` apenas a tabela `_Migrations` seria criada no banco de dados, com o primeiro registro de versão.

Quando o `Update-Database` foi criar a tabela `_Migrations`, também executou um erro:

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Essa deixarei para outra pergunta.

---

### Tirando o schema das classes de configuração do mapeamento (classes com Fluent)

Tentei também por tirar o nome do schema das classes de configuração:

De:

```
// Table & Column Mappings
ToTable("venda", "vendas"); // <-- Aqui está o schema/database name
```

Para:

```
ToTable("venda"); // <-- Aqui está o schema/database name
```

Mas então os migrations são gerados com o schema ***dbo.***.

Exemplo:

```
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.produto",  // <-- schema dbo.
        c => new
            {
                ...
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

E dessa forma também ao tentar aplicar o migration no banco de dados dá erro. Dessa vez acusa que as tabelas já existem.

> Table 'produto' already exists

Dá a entender que ele ignora o ***dbo.*** mas não trata como uma tabela já existente.

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema. Aparentemente está tudo certo. Qual seria o prefixo que as tabelas geradas pela *Migration* deveriam ter?

Comment: Olá @CiganoMorrisonMendez, obrigado pelo interesse. Desculpe se me expressei mal. Adicionei duas imagens, uma antes de usar `Migrations` e outra após efetuar o comando `Update-Database`.

Comment: Se alguém mais se interessar em ajudar, pode obter os fontes pelo GitHub. Grato! Link: https://github.com/JamesTKdev/Venda/tree/master

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode customizar o gerador de código para *Migrations*:

```
public class MeuProprioMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator : MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override MigrationStatement Generate(AddForeignKeyOperation addForeignKeyOperation)
    {
        addForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable = addForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable.Replace("vendas.", "");
        addForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable = addForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable.Replace("vendas.", "");
        MigrationStatement ms = base.Generate(addForeignKeyOperation);
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Registre-o no seu `Migrations/Configuration.cs`:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MeuProjeto.Models.MeuProjetoContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MeuProprioMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Reimplementei a classe errada. Adicione também a seguinte classe:

```
public class CustomMySqlMigrationCodeGenerator : MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Descomente para debugar
        // if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        var create = new CreateTableOperation(createTableOperation.Name.Replace("Vendas.", ""));

        foreach (var item in createTableOperation.Columns)
            create.Columns.Add(item);

        create.PrimaryKey = createTableOperation.PrimaryKey;

        base.Generate(create, writer);
    }
}
```

Se quiser trocar `createTableOperation.Name.Replace("Vendas.", "")` por uma solução genérica, fique à vontade.

A configuração ficou assim:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        CodeGenerator = new CustomMySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
        SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }
```

Fiz um *pull request* com as modificações [no seu repositório GitHub](https://github.com/JamesTKdev/Venda).

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui resolver o problema com seu exemplo e nem pelos métodos que encontrei em `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator`.

Comment: @JamesTK Fez um *debug*?

Comment: O que tentei foi utilizando Migrations, não dá para debugar. O que fiz foi tentar recriar o migration (Add-Migration Initial -force), continua aparecendo com prefixo "vendas". Tentei Update-Database para ver se iria remover o prefixo ao criar a base, mas continou criando outras tabelas.

Comment: Criei um exemplo em projeto console para inserir e listar registros no banco de dados. Funcionou sem causar alterações na base. Porém continuo com problemas ao tentar usar Migrations. Mas obrigado por tentar ajudar

Comment: @JamesTK Dá sim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169020/debug-code-first-entity-framework-migration-codes

Comment: Só consegui debugar sua classe de exemplo (`MeuProprioMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator`) com uma aplicação de teste. Mas pelo ***Package Manager Console***, utilizando os comandos `Add-Migration` e `Update-Database`, como havia dito, não dá para debugar.

Comment: Se ainda estiver interessado em me ajudar e quiser olhar mais de perto pode obter os fontes pelo GitHub: https://github.com/JamesTKdev/Venda/tree/master. Todavia, obrigado até agora!

Comment: @JamesTK Obrigado! Foi de grande ajuda. Já atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Meu pelo que vi você não pode usar essa abordagem. O code fist pressupõe que você não terá o banco de dados e iniciará seu desenvolvimento pelo código e não pelo banco. Segue link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765608/how-to-do-migrations-in-db-first-approach/19831142#19831142

Comment: Num esforço de reengenharia e expansão do sistema se baseando em uma base pré-existente, não vejo problema, até porque ele foi específico em dizer que faz questão de gerar uma base nova.

Comment: Depois de tudo, muito contente com o resultado =D

Answer (score 2):

#### Resumindo e sintetizando meu problema, as confusões em si que cometi e o que foi feito.

O **EntityFramework Power Tools**, pelo o que percebi, não fazer distinção de banco de dados ao gerar as classes de mapeamento.

Ao gerar as classes de mapeamento da minha base existente ele estava adicionando o nome do banco de dados como ***schema*** (apesar de se encontrar o termo ***schema*** no **MySQL** também, mas entendo o ***schema*** no **MySQL** como outra coisa, diferente do ***schema*** no **SQL Server**).

Exemplo do mapeamento:

```cs
public class ProdutoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Produto>
{
    public ProdutoMap()
    {
        ToTable("Produto", "Vendas");  // isso que ele faz
        ....
    }
}
```

Acredito que esse foi a principal confusão porque o **MySQL** não trabalha com ***schemas*** como o **SQL Server** e, ao gerar as classes de ***Migrations***, o nome do banco era anexado com um ponto ao nome da tabela como o ***schema*** é feito no **SQL Server**.

Então adicionei ao projeto os arquivos **T4** (**.tt**), para editar, e não adicionar mais o nome do banco de dados como nome de **schema**. Isso é necessário para qualquer outra base **MySQL** que se vá importar, principalmente com muitas tabelas.

E então as classes de mapeamento passaram a ter o método ToTable escrito dessa forma pela engenharia reversa do **EF Power Tools**:

```cs
public class ProdutoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Produto>
{
    public ProdutoMap()
    {
        ToTable("Produto");  // sem um nome para o esquema.
        ....
    }
}
```

### Porém...

Até a ilustre e paciente ajuda do colega **Cigano** eu não tinha feito isso, estava deixando o nome do banco como nome de ***schema*** lá na classe de mapeamento e querendo gerar um ***Migration*** corretamente.

O colega Cigano quebrando cabeça para entender minha confusão atacou com as classes para geração de **SQL** do **MySQL** e a de geração de código (das classes de **Migrations**).

Certo, resolveu!!! *=]*

Obrigado, e já marquei como resposta aceita e a mais que merecida recompensa foi dada.

Todavia fiquei pensando, ao estar sobrescrevendo mais métodos da `CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator` e da `CustomMySqlMigrationCodeGenerator` herdadas de `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator` e `MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator` (o exemplo pode ser visto nesse histórico do **[GitHub](https://github.com/JamesTKdev/Venda/pull/1/files)** no arquivo **[Configuration.cs](https://github.com/cigano/Venda/blob/27c89f2db697c27352ad14aae44ac4ead0e2c76a/Venda.Repositorio/Migrations/Configuration.cs)**)... Não é possível que tenham liberado as dll´s de suporte ao **EF** com esse problema de nome para as tabelas.

**Então, o que antes estava configurado como:**

```cs
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<VendasContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        CodeGenerator = new CustomMySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
        SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", 
            (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }
}
```

**Testei com:**

```cs
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<VendasContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        CodeGenerator = new MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", 
            (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }
}
```

Ou seja, sem precisar das classes que estávamos utilizando para remover o nome do **banco do nome/*schema*** da tabela.

Para finalizar, ainda não entendi porque estavam sendo gerados Migrations para as tabelas já existentes no banco de dados, então removi manualmente:

```cs
namespace Venda.Repositorio.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initial : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

E efetuei o comando `Update-Database`.

A tabela `__migrations` foi adicionada ao banco com o registro da primeira versão.

Adicionei mais uma propriedade na classe `Venda`, chamada `Observacao` do tipo `string` e mandei gerar mais um ***Migration***.

**Maravilha, funcionou:**

```cs
namespace Venda.Repositorio.Migrations
{
    public partial class Versao_2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("Venda", "Observacao", 
                c => c.String(unicode: false, storeType: "text"));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("Venda", "Observacao");
        }
    }
}
```

Então, `Update-Database` novamente e ocorreu tudo bem!!

Estou trabalhando com **MySQL**, **EF** e usando ***Migrations*** sem problemas.

Grato!

Comment: Testei com o `CodeGenerator` padrão do MySQL mas não funcionou, aí acabei escrevendo meu próprio `CodeGenerator`. Enfim, seu roteiro é ótimo para converter um *database-first* para um *code-first*. +1.